# SAPUI5 Smart Filter Bar Case Sensitive Search

Tags: sapui5

In my SAPUI5 application, there is a Smart Table and Smart Filter Bar. And I've implemented filters using local annotation **ValueList**. Filters working fine and provide suggestions while typing correctly.

But the problem is the search is Case Sensitive. So I've to type words in exact case in order to get the results. Is there any configuration to switch off or any method to disable the case sensitivity of the filters of the smart filter bar.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any direct configuration or method for this, but you can do something like this:

```
oSmartTable.attachBeforeRebindTable(function(oEvent) {
    var oBindingParams = oEvent.getParameter( "bindingParams" );
    oBindingParams.filters[0].aFilters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter('someProperty' ,'Contains', 'something'));
});
```

Above I'm adding a new filter, which is then used in the binding. You could of course instead find your target filter in `aFilters` and change the case of `value1`.

The alternative would be to change the filter functionality in the backend to be case insensitive.